# How to check if a HMD in Unity 2018 is in use?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I was wondering if there was a way to check whether the sensor detects an object in the HMD. Specifically, this is in regards to the current latest version of Unity and the Oculus Rift CV1.

The reason why I wish to do this is for pausing my game, when the user is not wearing their HMD.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the Unity version and has changed over time. It's usually the `VRDevice.isPresent` property which has been renamed on some version. There is an issue with it in the *Unity 5.2* and below so `VRSettings.loadedDevice` should be used for 5.2 and below.

For *Unity 5.2* and below, you need the `UnityEngine.VR` namespace:

```
if (VRSettings.loadedDevice != VRDeviceType.None)
{

}
```

For Unity 5.3 and above, you need the `UnityEngine.VR` namespace

```
if (VRDevice.isPresent)
{

}
```

For *Unity 2017.2* and above, you need the `UnityEngine.XR` namespace:

```
if (XRDevice.isPresent)
{

}
```

---

The examples above check if the device is present. To check if they are in use by the user:

```
if (XRDevice.userPresence == UserPresenceState.Present)
{

}
```

or

```
if (VRDevice.userPresence == UserPresenceState.Present)
{

}
```